# Issuing and handling asynchronous webservice requests in a Thread

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

My silverlight application has a piece of code that issues multiple asynchronous requests to a web service and fills a collection from the data it returns. Is it possible to move the entire issuing (multiple calls) and handling all the responses to a single background thread. The purpose is to make UI faster.

Comment: What sort of service is it?  asmx? WCF? a simple .ashx?  something else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes potentially.

You can set up a background worker object and pass into it the very object that will be making the multiple async' calls.The background worker class has a method called 'RunWorkerAsync(object)'.

[Background Worker Class MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Everything you need to know about this class is found on the link above. Be sure to read the the remarks section.

[To get you started look here ...](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/BackgroundWorker_sample.aspx)

> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events. < MSDN
>
> To set up for a background operation, add an event handler for the DoWork event. Call your time-consuming operation in this event handler. To start the operation, call RunWorkerAsync. To receive notifications of progress updates, handle the ProgressChanged event. To receive a notification when the operation is completed, handle the RunWorkerCompleted event. < MSDN

Lastly ...
[Silverlight Performance Tips on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am familiar with BackgroundWorker. I need to know how to issue Async webservice calls (not async of worker) and handle it (Async_completed event handler) from one BackgroundWorker.